# Select all text without removing h-tags

Tags: ckeditor

I am using the inline shared CKEditor (version 4.5.7) in a CMS.

To simplify editing new elements in the page-builder, I use the following code if the text in the container is dummy-text:

```
editor.on( 'focus', function(ev) {
    if(obj.isDummyText($(ev.editor.element.$))) {
        ev.editor.execCommand( 'selectAll' );
    }
});
```

The problem is, if the container has a initial styling set, like a h-tag, the h-tag gets stripped when you start typing.

I want to maintain that h-tag in the element so an initial style is already set and the UX is a bit better.

I have tried fixing this with the CKEDITOR.config:

```
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
config.forcePasteAsPlainText = false;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['i']  = false;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['h1'] = false;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['h2'] = false;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['h3'] = false;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['h4'] = false;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['h5'] = false;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['h6'] = false;
config.allowedContent = true;
```

Sadly this didn't change anything, the h-tags still get stripped when you start typing:

Before selection:

[image: Before selecting]

While selecting:

[image: Selection]

And after I started typing:

[image: After typing]

---

Is there any way to fix/hack this issue?

Comment: Are you able to provide a working example?

Comment: Added a fiddle :)

Comment: Are you sure the fiddle show the problem? I don't see any selection there...

Comment: This issue only persists in firefox or IE, just click on the text and select all text with ctrl + a, then start typing, you see the h4 tag being removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to create a new selectionRange for the content of the `h4` element (without the `h4` element itself):

```
editor.on('focus', function(ev) {
    setTimeout(function() {
    var element = element = ev.editor.document.getElementsByTag('h4').getItem(0).$;
    var textNode = element.childNodes[0];

    var startIndex = 0;
    var endIndex = textNode.length;

    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(textNode, startIndex);
    range.setEnd(textNode, endIndex);

    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  }, 100);
})
```

The code worked great on all browsers but IE without the `setTimeout` function, so I added this.

Here is a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/dhxpyobo/

Comment: Awesome!!! And then catch the ctrl+a shortcut also with a keydown event?  Because the shortcut still selects all innerHTML

Comment: You've earned it, I've been searching a solution for this for a while now :D

Comment: Glad I could help.